# Find data in list (Filter)

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a list with fields

I need to filter only on a specific parameter

Model:

```
class Doc {

    static constraints = {
        name()
        parameter(inList: ["Список",
                        "Строка",
                        "Число"])
    }

    String name
    List parameter
}
```

In index.gsp

```
<label for="query">Where:</label>
<g:select value="${params.parameter}" name="parameter" from="${parameterList}" noSelection="['':'All parameter']" />
```

In controller

```
def index(Integer max) {
    params.max = Math.min(params.max ? params.int('max') : 2, 10)

    def parameterList = Doc.parameter.list()

    if (params.parameter != "" ) {
        def item = parameterList.find { p -> inList(p.parameter, "%${params.parameter}%")}
    }

    [params: params, parameterList: parameterList]

}
```

That is, for example

There are data:

name: *a1* parameter: *[[list], [string]]*

name: *a2* parameter: *[[list], [number]]*

name: *a3* parameter: *[number]*

I choose to filter by **"number"** and I only need to get two values of **"a2"** and **"a3"**

Answer (score 0):

```
//your params data sample (not sure about this point)
def params=[
    a1: ['123','234'],
    a2: [123,234],
    a3: 123,
    a4: '123',
]
//the filter
def filter = "number"
//map from filter to filtering class
def filterClazz = [
    number: Number.class,
    string: CharSequence.class,
].get(filter)
//the filter logic
def filteredKeys = params.findAll{k,v->
    //if value is collection then lookup if any element instance of our filter class
    if (v instanceof Collection)return v.find{filterClazz.isInstance(it)}
    //otherwise (not collection) just check if value is filter class 
    return filterClazz.isInstance(v);
}.collect{it.getKey()} //collect only key names

println filteredKeys
```